# How to model constraints between 'building blocks'?

Tags: constraints, faces

I am creating an application where users can build a structure by 'clicking' together building blocks. Each block is multi-faced with geomnetry based on an octagon, and the blocks can click on to each other 'face-to-face' only with faces aligned.
I presume I will need to use constraints for this but cannot see how to use those in Blender currently? Any suggestions?